# how to deal with a copy-pasted table in pandas- reshaping a column vector

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a table I copied from a [webpage](https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/) which when pasted into librecalc or excel occupies a single cell, and when pasted into notebook becomes a 3507x1 column. If I import this as a pandas dataframe using pd.read_csv I see the same 3507x1 column , and I'd now like to reshape it into the 501x7 array that it started as.

I thought I could recast as a numpy array, reshape as I am familiar with in numpy and then put back into a df, but the to_numpy methods of pandas seem to want to work with a Series object (not Dataframe) and attempts to read the file into a Series using eg

```
ser= pd.Series.from_csv('billionaires')
```

led to tokenizing errors. Is there some simple way to do this? Maybe I should throw in the towel on this direction and read from the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that converting to a numpy array was far easier than I had realized - the numpy asarray method can handle a df (and conveniently enough it  works for general objects, not just numbers)

```
df = pd.read_csv('billionaires',sep='\n')
print(df.shape)
   ->  (3507, 1)
n = np.asarray(df)
m = np.reshape(n,[-1,7])
df2=pd.DataFrame(m)
df2.head()

   0                1                2              3             4  \
0  0             Name  Total net worth  $ Last change  $ YTD change   
1  1       Jeff Bezos            $121B         +$231M       -$3.94B   
2  2       Bill Gates            $107B         -$421M       +$16.7B   
3  3  Bernard Arnault            $104B         +$127M       +$35.7B   
4  4   Warren Buffett           $84.9B        +$66.3M       +$1.11B   

               5            6  
0        Country     Industry  
1  United States   Technology  
2  United States   Technology  
3         France     Consumer  
4  United States  Diversified
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple copy paste does not give you any clear column separator, so it's impossible to do it easily.
You have only spaces, but spaces may or may not be inside the column values too (like in the name or country) so is impossible to give to `DataFrame.read_csv` a column separator.

However, if I copy paste the table in a file, I notice regularity.
If you know regex, you can try using [pandas.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html). This method extracts capture groups in a regex pattern as columns of a DataFrame. The regex is applied to each element / string of the series.

You can then try to find a regex pattern to capture the various elements of the row to split them into separate columns.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', names=["A"]) #no header in the file
ss = df['A']
rdf = ss.str.extract('(\d)\s+(.+)(\$[\d\.]+B)\s+([+-]\$[\d\.]+[BM])\s+([+-]\$[\d\.]+B)\s+([\w\s]+)\s+([\w\s]+)')
```

Here I tried to write a regex for the table in the link, the result on the first seems pretty good.

```
   0                              1       2        3        4                    5            6
0  1                    Jeff Bezos    $121B   +$231M  -$3.94B       United States    Technology
1  3               Bernard Arnault    $104B   +$127M  +$35.7B              France      Consumer
2  4                Warren Buffett   $84.9B  +$66.3M  +$1.11B       United States   Diversified
3  5               Mark Zuckerberg   $76.7B   -$301M  +$24.6B       United States    Technology
4  6                Amancio Ortega   $66.5B   +$303M  +$7.85B               Spain        Retail
5  7                 Larry Ellison   $62.3B   +$358M  +$13.0B       United States    Technology
6  8                   Carlos Slim   $57.0B   -$331M  +$2.20B              Mexico   Diversified
7  9  Francoise Bettencourt Meyers   $56.7B  -$1.12B  +$10.5B              France      Consumer
8  0                    Larry Page   $55.7B   +$393M  +$4.47B       United States    Technology
```

I used `DataFrame.read_csv` to read the file, since `Series.from_csv' is deprecated.

Comment: but it skips anything not fitting the pattern , e.g. Bill Gates has escaped the regex , allowing him to emit another windows version.  I need all the rows for further work

Comment: I did not try all the rows of the table. If there are rows with a more complex pattern, the regex should be edited accordingly.

Comment: imho the direct method outlined above is easier than trying a regex and patching it when it breaks